# GeoJson file & leaflet: can't get toolTip to display

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a leaflet map and I managed to display colored circle markers for several weather stations, with tooltips (temperature) and also popups (other weather info). Everything is fine, but the json data is inline and cannot be changed, so I used it only for testing purposes.

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([39.0320,-8.4753], 7);
           
  L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    minZoom: 3,
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
  
  }).addTo(map);

var weather = [
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-9.13, 39.4]
    },
    "properties": {
        "place": "CALDAS DA RAINHA",
        "temp": "25.3",
        "vento": "5.8",
        "humid": "35",
        }
},
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-8.13, 39.4]
    },
    "properties": {
        "place": "ABRANTES",
        "temp": "21.7",
        "vento": "15.8",
        "humid": "42",
    }
},
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-8.13, 38.4]
    },
    "properties": {
        "place": "Viana do Alentejo",
        "temp": "18.3",
        "vento": "22.7",
        "humid": "57",
    }
},
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-7.43, 38.7]
    },
    "properties": {
        "place": "Alandroal",
        "temp": "12.1",
        "vento": "34.5",
        "humid": "68",
    }
}
];

var json = new L.geoJson(weather, {
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
    
        if (feature.properties.temp >= 25.0) {
        return new L.CircleMarker([latlng.lat, latlng.lng],
        {radius: 15,
          fillColor: "red", 
          fillOpacity: 0.8, 
          color: "#555555", 
          weight: 0.2, 
          opacity: 0.1, 
        })
        }
        if (feature.properties.temp >= 20.0) {
        return new L.CircleMarker([latlng.lat, latlng.lng],
        {radius: 15,
          fillColor: "orange",
          fillOpacity: 0.8, 
          color: "#555555", 
          weight: 0.2,
          opacity: 0.1,
        })
        }
        if (feature.properties.temp >= 15.0) {
        return new L.CircleMarker([latlng.lat, latlng.lng],
        {radius: 15,
          fillColor: "#ffcc00",
          fillOpacity: 0.8, 
          color: "#555555",
          weight: 0.2,
          opacity: 0.1, 
        })
        }
        if (feature.properties.temp >= 10.0) {
        return new L.CircleMarker([latlng.lat, latlng.lng],
        {radius: 15,
          fillColor: "green",
          fillOpacity: 0.8, 
          color: "#555555", 
          weight: 0.2,
          opacity: 0.1, 
        })
        }
        },
    
      onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        
        // TOOLTIP
        var temp = L.tooltip({
            permanent: true,
            direction: 'center',
            className: 'temp'
        })
        .setContent(feature.properties.temp)
        .setLatLng(layer.getLatLng())
        
        temp.addTo(map); //adicionar a variável temp ao mapa
      
        //POPUP             
            var popupText = "<b><span style='background-color:#fff;color:#ff5500'>" + feature.properties.place +
            "</span></b><br>Temperatura:<b> " + feature.properties.temp + 
                "</b>º<br>Vento:<b> " + feature.properties.vento +
                "</b> km/h<br>Humidade:<b> " + feature.properties.humid + "</b>%";
        
        layer.bindPopup(popupText, {
            closeButton: true,
            offset: L.point(0, 0)
        });
        layer.on('click', function() {
            layer.openPopup();
            });
            
    }
}).addTo(map);

var scale = L.control.scale({metric:true,imperial:false, maxWidth:200})
        scale.addTo(map) //variavel escala adicionada ao mapa
```

```css
 html,
 body,
 #map {
   margin: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }

.leaflet-tooltip-pane .temp {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
    crossorigin=""/>

    <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og=="
    crossorigin=""></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" 
      integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" 
      crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I tried to replace the inline data from an external geojson file, the tooltips didn't work anymore. The geojson file has been tested and is ok. Basicaly what I did was to replace the inline

```
var weather = [
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-9.13, 39.4]
    },
    "properties": {
        "place": "CALDAS DA RAINHA",
                "temp": "25.3",
        "vento": "5.8",
                "humid": "35",
        }
},
{ 
...
 var json = new L.geoJson(weather, {
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
    
        if (feature.properties.temp >= 25.0) {
          return new L.CircleMarker([latlng.lat, latlng.lng],
          {radius: 15,
          fillColor: "red", 
          fillOpacity: 0.8, 
          color: "#555555", 
          weight: 0.2, 
          opacity: 0.1, 
        })
    ...
```

with this

```
$.getJSON('https://meteolitoral.com/test.geojson', function(data) {

var datalayer = L.geoJson(data, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                
        if (feature.properties.temp >= 30.0) {
            return new L.CircleMarker([latlng.lat, latlng.lng],
                {radius: 15,
                fillColor: "#ffcc00",
                fillOpacity: 0.8, 
                color: "#555555", 
                weight: 0.2,
                opacity: .1, 
            })
        }
        ...
```

Fiddle doesn't give me any error and in any browser, it displays the map with colored marks and the popups, but tooltips (displaying temperature), do not show up!!!
I wondered if problem was here

```
 onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    
    // TOOLTIP
    var temp = L.tooltip({
        permanent: true,
        direction: 'center',
        className: 'temp'
    })
    .setContent(feature.properties.temp)
    .setLatLng(layer.getLatLng())
    temp.addTo(map);
```

but despite trying similar questions and answers here in StackOFlow, and extensive google search, none gave me a clue to solve this problem of the tooltips not working!
I finnaly gave up, and that is why I am asking for some help!

Answer (score 1):

Your map is fine, but for the fetch to work, Cross Origin Requests (CORS) need to be enabled on this domain - https://meteolitoral.com/test.geojson

Comment: Thank you so much Edwin for your precious help! I had no idea I had to enable CORS :-) 
In my script, I fetch the geojson file from server (cache/test.geojson) and I get a populated map with circle markers and popups, but tooltips don't show up. Is this related to CORS? It can be seen here https://meteolitoral.com/novo7.html